# Flowable in room

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-room

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract userDao userDao();
}
```

**Pojo user class**

```
@Entity
    public class User {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        private int id;

        public User(){
        }



        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface userDao {
            @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = :id")
            Flowable<User> get(int id);
            @Insert
            Completable insert(User user);
        }
```

**Dependencies**

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.14"
```

**Error**

```
error: no suitable method found for createFlowable(RoomDatabase,boolean,String[],<anonymous Callable<User>>)
method RxRoom.createFlowable(RoomDatabase,String...) is not applicable
(varargs mismatch; boolean cannot be converted to String)
method RxRoom.<T>createFlowable(RoomDatabase,String[],Callable<T>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>createFlowable(RoomDatabase,String[],Callable<T>)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to work with rxjava in the room, I follow the examples, but it throws an error, what is the problem? Completable works fine

Comment: Did you solve this problem? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Room Declaring Dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies), you need a dependency on `room-ktx` to use Coroutines and, with that, `Flowable`:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.3"
```

Comment: Didnt help in my case.

Answer (score 10):

I have no idea why you marked **ianhanniballake**'s answer as a correct one.
Dependency "**androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.3**" has nothing to do with RxJava.
I my case I fixed the problem by adding this dependency

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.3"
```

insted of my old one:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1'
```

hope this will help

Comment: Worked for me also . Thanks a lot